# "Not enough storage space" when installed with Dynamic Feature Module (App Bundle)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, dfm

I have a unity project (exported using Unity 2019.3) installed dynamically with DFM of Android App Bundle and uploaded it to google play for internal testing, the dynamic module is downloading fine on demand but when I run UnityActivity I encounter the following error:"Not enough storage space to install required resources" even though I have lot of free space in my mobile device. What I am missing here? [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfZXG.jpg)

Comment: did u find a fix for this issue?

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Is your android phone using a SD Card?

Comment: What is the filepath you are trying to save to, and how are you saving it? Please include the related code.

Comment: are you sure its a unity bug and not device issue?

Comment: how much space does the bundle take up? And which version of AndroidStudio are you using?

Comment: @Thiyagarajan Purushothaman - Were you able to finally use unity.aar as a dynamic feature in Android app. In my case all the unity so files are getting included in Base apk itself, not giving me any benefit for DyanamicFeature module. Can you help me here?

Answer (score 2):

Please check if src/main/assets/bin/Data/ exists and contains contents from unity.
What normally happens it's the default gitignore in a vcs project will ignore bin folders and thats right except in unity projects.

Answer (score 1):

We just solved a "not enough storage space to install required resources" error thanks to firetrap answer.
Thank you so much!

We had just to white listed "unityLibrary/src/main/assets/bin" folder (that default android studio .gitignore ignored).
We were building on a Jenkins server and that folder was not being pushed from the machine we used to export the Unity project to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, cannot comment because don't have enough reputation anymore.

No, don't use the SD card.

Unity is added as a library so everything is Unity default logic. Have to dig deeper into the Unity source code and see if able to find a place where is a file path.

Compiling the same code from different machines and the result is different. From some machines, unity doesn't give that error and everything works correctly but from some machines, unity gives that error. Tested APK with different mobile devices, if error then different mobile devices give that error, is no error then it works in different devices. Deleted also Android Studio with all settings and installed again but no success. No idea why compiling code from some machines this error occurs.